# How to add client side event on asp:menu item click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using `<asp:Menu>` control in my web site and populated it from my Sql Server database table using XML data source.
Now i want to add a client side event on menu item click.
When a user clicks any menu item i need to show a please wait dialog window until the page got complete refreshed.
For that i need to run my java script function on client click.
So can any one tell me how to add a client side click event on menu item click.

Comment: Be clear what you looking for? Input and output ?

Comment: I just want to execute a JavaScript function on <asp:menu> item click event.Just like we can call a JavaScript function on Button Client click.
Ex.
><asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" 
 CssClass="btn" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click"
 OnClientClick="doClear();return document.errVal"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved by adding css classes

```
<DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicMenu" />
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="primaryStaticMenu"/>
```

And then add this jquery function for main-menu items:

```
$(function() {
    $(".primaryStaticMenu a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
});
```

For sub-menu items:

```
$(function() {
    $(".primaryDynamicMenu a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
});
```